# extract values from regular expression : c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have string "1P2R". I just want to extract count of P & R from it using regular expression.
I  tried the following codes, but didn't work.

```
String regex = "[0-9]+[P]?[0-9]+[R]?";
String input = "1P2R";
MatchCollection coll = Regex.Matches(input, regex);
String result = coll[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

or

```
String regex = "[0-9]+[P]?[0-9]+[R]?";
String input = "1P2R";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, regex);
if (match.Success)
  {
      string key = match.Value;
  }
```

Both methods were not giving the result. How I can achieve this?

I have changed the code as follows...

```
String regex = "[0-9]+[P]?[0-9]+[R]?";
String input = "1P2R";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, regex);
if (match.Success)
{
string a, b;
a = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf("P"));
b = input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf("P") + 1, input.LastIndexOf("R") - input.LastIndexOf("P")-1);
}
```

is it ok?

Regards
Sebastian

Comment: How do you want to extract count of `P` and `R`? Dou you mean chars count? If yes, dou have to use regex?

Comment: you need to capture `P` and `R`.`String regex = "[0-9]+([P])?[0-9]+([R])?";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match the numbers before P and R, use this:

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"([0-9]+)P([0-9]+)R");
var myMatch = myRegex.Match(yourString);
string pCount = myMatch.Groups[1].Value;
string rCount = myMatch.Groups[2].Value;
Console.WriteLine(pcount,rcount);
```

**Explanation**

- `([0-9]+)` captures one or more digits to Group 1
- `P` matches `P`
- `([0-9]+)` captures one or more digits to Group 2
- `R` matches `R`

Comment: One issue.. This is working for string "2P1R", if we reverse it : say "2R1P", it is not working.

Comment: If you want it to be either `P` or `R`, use `@"([0-9]+)[PR]([0-9]+)[PR]"`

Comment: Good info, But one Problem: Value of P gets assigned to R & vice versa.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do now. Then we have to use a different approach: `@"(?=.*([0-9]+)P)(?=.*([0-9]+)R)"`

Comment: For an explanation of the comment just above, please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24472179/1078583) that I wrote some time ago—same technique. :)

Comment: I have an additional query on this. I want to know which is the first character, is it 'P' or 'R'.

Comment: I have tried the below method, but didn't work..
        public static Dictionary<string, string> GetSelectValuesDictionary(string inputString)
        {
            return Regex.Matches(inputString, @"(?=.*([0-9]+)P)(?=.*([0-9]+)R)")
              .Cast<Match>()
              .ToDictionary(
                  m => m.Groups["key"].Value,
                  m => m.Groups["value"].Value);
        }

Comment: one more finding, this expression fails, if we give values greater than 9

Comment: Indeed. `@"(?=.*?([0-9]+)P)(?=.*?([0-9]+)R)"`

Answer (score 0):

Hi to count the number of occurrence of a character in a string you can use following code segment:

```
class countPR
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String s="1P2R1P2R1P2R1P2R1P2R1P2R1P2R1P2R";        
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".P");
    //  get a matcher object
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    int countP = 0;
    while(m.find()) 
    {
        countP++;           
    }
    System.out.println("P found "+countP+" number of times");

    p = Pattern.compile(".R");
    m = p.matcher(s);
    int countR = 0;
    while(m.find()) 
    {
        countR++;           
    }
    System.out.println("R found "+countR+" number of times");
}
```

}

Comment: pattern & matcher are not available? is it framework specific?

Comment: @SebastianXavier that seems more like Java than C#... Java uses pattern/matcher,

Comment: @SebastianXavier yeah that was a code segment of Java you can use follwong code segment for C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegExApplication
{
class Program
{
  private static void showMatch(string text, string expr)
  {
     int count=0;
     Console.WriteLine("The Expression: " + expr);
     MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(text, expr);
     foreach (Match m in mc)
     {
        count++;
     }
     Console.WriteLine(expr+" found "+count+" number of times");
  }
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     string str = "1P2R1P2R1P2R1P2R1P2R1P2R1P2R1P2RGIRISHBALODI";

     Console.WriteLine("Matching words that start with 'S': ");
     showMatch(str, @".P");
     showMatch(str, @".R");
     Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
}
```